# How to install magit manual?

Tags: emacs, elpa

I have magit installed on my system with elpa. However, it comes without documentation, and that makes using it a hassle (since help on its mode is somewhat lacking).

Is there a way consistent with using emacs package manager to install documentation on magit as well?

Comment: While not an answer to your question, you are most likely interested in functions within that package that are `interactive`, and the doc-strings of those `interactive` functions may be helpful.  Here is a link to a **Magit Cheatsheet**:  http://daemianmack.com/magit-cheatsheet.html and here is a link to some Magit documentation:  http://magit.github.io/documentation.html

Comment: Well, your second link has just the documentation i want installed locally. As far as i can tell, it is, when magit is installed as a debian package. I would like to be able to access that help without leaving emacs, though.